# stripos can't find a value

Tags: php, php-7

As you see in output, stripos can't catch _formtoken value, anyone can explain it to me with solution :

```
$value = ['_formtoken','expiry','version','pan','expiry','purchAmount','_formtoken','pan'];
for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){

  if (stripos($added, $value[$i]) == false) { 
      echo $value[$i] . ' => Not exists in <br>';    
      $added .= $value[$i];
  } 
  else { 
          echo $value[$i] . ' => already exists  <br>'; 
  } 

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
_formtoken => Not exists in
expiry => Not exists in
version => Not exists in
pan => Not exists in
expiry => already exists
purchAmount => Not exists in
_formtoken => Not exists in
pan => already exists
```

Comment: Where does `$added` come from?

Comment: just empty variable to add values into it

Answer (score 1):

stripos may return 0 or false. If the string you are searching for is at the beginning of the search string, it will return 0. If you use this in an if statement it will evaluate to false. To fix this, use `===`.

```
$value = ['_formtoken','expiry','version','pan','expiry','purchAmount','_formtoken','pan'];
$added = null;
for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
  $pos = stripos($added, $value[$i]);
  if ( $pos === false) { 
      echo $value[$i] . ' => Not exists in <br>' . "\n";    
      $added .= $value[$i];
  } 
  else { 
      echo $value[$i] . ' => already exists  <br>'."\n"; 
  } 
}
```

When I run it, this is the output I see.

```
_formtoken => Not exists in <br>
expiry => Not exists in <br>
version => Not exists in <br>
pan => Not exists in <br>
expiry => already exists  <br>
purchAmount => Not exists in <br>
_formtoken => already exists  <br>
pan => already exists  <br>
```

Comment: stripos doesnt detecte the value inside text, test this code to see
 $value = ['_formtoken','=333&version=2.0&pan=4552945074567017&expiry=2211&purchAmount=150&exponent=2&description=Donation&_formtoken='];
for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
      
  if (stripos($added, $value[$i]) === false) { 
      echo $value[$i] . ' => Not exists in <br>';    
      $added .= $value[$i]."&";
  } 
  else { 
          echo $value[$i] . ' => exists  <br>'; 
  } 
  
}

Comment: Are you suggesting that stripos does not work as documented?

Comment: I ran your code snippet. Looks fine to me

Comment: You can see here: https://repl.it/repls/YellowCrazyRoutes

Comment: Check this screenshot : https://i.paste.pics/49cfafc699f83b28110c2cff6d5b6115.png

stripos cant catch it inside text.

Comment: @ElarbiDafrouillah because `_formtoken=7f9D&_formtoken=4ee3` is not a substring of `_formtoken`.

Comment: The problem have been solved by using Regex. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It looks as though you're trying to create a single string of each of the unique values within your array, is that correct? If so, try this instead, it's far cleaner:

```php
$inputArray = ['_formtoken', 'expiry', 'version', 'pan', 'expiry', 'purchAmount', '_formtoken', 'pan'];

// Only keep the first occurrence of each value
$uniqueInputArray = array_unique($inputArray);

// Output the values separated by a single space between each
echo implode(' ', $uniqueInputArray);
```

Or as a single line:

```php
echo implode(' ', array_unique(['_formtoken', 'expiry', 'version', 'pan', 'expiry', 'purchAmount', '_formtoken', 'pan']));
```

Comment: #looking to use it as condition, Thanks

Comment: The question was about `substr`, not how to make a string from unique values in an array.